# How to make Search Bar first responder when I hide current Table view and unhide other

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uisearchbar

I have two Table Views in a UIViewController.  On page load, 2ndTableView and its search bar remain hidden :

```
homeTableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
```

When I click Search Bar on the screen, table view and its search bar hide and, other table view and its search bar unhide as I expected.

```
   func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {

    homeTableView.hidden = false
    shareTableView.hidden = true
    homeSearchBar.hidden = true
    return true
}
```

But the problem is, when other search bar comes to screen, I need to click on it to make a search.  But I want to make it first responder (I mean I don't want to click on it again) when it display on the screen. If I run following command, the hidden search bar display immediately on screen load.

```
searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
```

Comment: what is the name of the other search bar that you are talking about?

Comment: It is @IBOutlet weak var homeSearchBar: UISearchBar!

Comment: ok when you call searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
did you check how many times searchBarShouldBeginEditing() delegate is called??

Comment: Actually, it looks like same of Instagram search.   On Instagram, when I click on search, I think another table view and another search bar display on the screen. And, new search bar is ready to write without clicking on it.  But, on my app, I need to click on new search bar to search something.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to build but how many times does the delegate method called?? how many UISearchBar objects do you have?

Comment: I call searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder() in   configureSearchController() function.   And searchBarShouldBeginEditing() delegate is not called because the Outlet homeSearchBar does not display on the screen and I don't click on it.

Comment: I have two ; one is UISearchBar outlet  and the other one is created by homeTableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99704/discussion-between-satheeshwaran-and-ozzy).